# Meteor S3 Download

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, meteor, download

I have managed to do upload using ***edgee:slingshot*** but currently lost on how to do download. I want the user to be able to download the attachment. I tried using:

`<a download href="s3url.com"></a>`
 but it only works on pdf and images which are viewable in the browser but I have an authentication error on download doc files and others files that are not viewable in the browser. Can someone please help. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like an issue with your S3 configuration or metadata.

Comment: @gladsocc really. How do I resolve this? Is it a bucket policy issue? What should I put in there?

Comment: @gladsocc stupid mistake, the error was that the file name had spaces. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it was a stupid mistake, the file name had spaces so the link is broken. Lol